# Add table controls for asp.net mvc web application using signalR

Tags: asp.net-mvc, signalr

I want to add controls to sort a table which is rendered in a partial view. The partial view is called using a signalR method. Every time the server updates the database with new information it calls the javascript method to return a new partial view to `<div id="customersTable">`.

I need a way to pass a query to the controller, and make the last query sent persistent so that when signalR calls the controller action again, the clients actions are remembered.

In addition to sorting I would also like to implement child rows that are expandable via a toggle button in an additional column. I'm not sure how feasible that is using partial views and signalR in this way.

I have partially solved this by adding JQuery controls to the main page. However when AJAX updates the DOM, the controls are reset to their default state, which is something I ultimately want to avoid happening.

Here is the partial view:

```
@model IEnumerable<XXXX.Models.CustomerModel>

<table class="table table-hover">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th class="col-sm-2">
                Name
            </th>
            <th class="col-sm-2">
                SO Number
            </th>
            <th class="col-sm-2">
                Report Time
            </th>
            <th class="col-sm-2">
                Report Date
            </th>
            <th align="center" class="col-sm-1">
                System Status
            </th>
        </tr>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr onclick="location.href = '@(Url.Action("SystemDetails", "Monitoring", new { id = item.ID }))'" @(item.Errors == 0 ? String.Empty : "class=danger")>
                <td class="col-sm-2">
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
                </td>
                <td class="col-sm-2">
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.SONumber)
                </td>
                <td class="col-sm-2">
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ReportTime)
                </td>
                <td class="col-sm-2">
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ReportDate)
                </td>
                <td align="center" class="col-sm-1">
                    @if (item.Errors == 0)
                    {
                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></i>
                    }
                    else if (item.Errors > 0)
                    {
                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-warning-sign"></i>
                    }
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Here is the javascript method client side:

```
function getAllCustomers()
    {
        var tbl = $('#customersTable');
        $.ajax({
            url: '/Monitoring/GetCustomers',
            contentType: 'application/html ; charset:utf-8',
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'html'
        }).success(function (result) {
            tbl.empty().append(result);
        }).error(function () {

        });
    }
```

And the controller method where the db context is sorted:

```
public ActionResult GetCustomers()
    {
        return PartialView("~/Views/Monitoring/_CustomersList.cshtml", db.Customers.OrderBy(c => c.SONumber).ToList());
    }
```